# Getting totals from sub-report to main report using Jasper Reports / iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

i want to calculate some totals on a subreport and use that in the main report. How can this be done?

/Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store the value that you want to return from your subreport into a variable in your subreport. Then in your main report in the subreport properties there is an option to select return variables from the subreport.